# Имя модуля в переменной

Tags: perl

Есть ряд модулей, которые содержат метод `Run`.
Нужно подключить модуль, имя которого содержит переменная `$var` и вызвать из него метод `Run`.

Comment: В чем у Вас проблема? В Вашем вопросе нет собственно вопроса. Пожалуйста ознакомьтесь с разделом справки [как задавать вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) и переформулируйте свой вопрос так чтобы Вам смогли дать на него ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Modern::Perl;
use Const::Fast;

const my $METHOD => 'Run';
my @modlist = qw/a::a b::b/;

for( @modlist )
{
  eval "use $_;";
  if( $@ ) {
    say "Can not load module $_: $@";
    next;
  }
  my $method = $_->can($METHOD);
  unless( $method ) {
    say "Module $_ does not contain method $METHOD!";
    next;
  }
  $method->();
}
```